# MPI Spawn method gives not enough slots error

Tags: python, mpi, openmpi, spawn, mpi4py

I am trying to run a script (in parallel execution) within another python script (which is MPI singleton) using following command:

`MPI.COMM_WORLD.Spawn(sys.executable, args=["hello.py"], maxprocs=10)`

It gives following error: 
There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 10
slots that were requested by the application.

I know that my laptop has 10 processors ([Processor](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/226066/intel-core-i712650h-processor-24m-cache-up-to-4-70-ghz/specifications.html)). When I run the script as `mpirun -n 10 python hello.py`, it creates 10 processes. But, when I use spawn method, it gives above error **only** when the maxprocs argument exceeds 5. Below 5, it works fine. I also tried to use `MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn()` method, but it shows same behavior.

I am not sure what is causing this error. I am suspecting that the number of performance cores in my processor is 6 which might be limiting the maxprocs to 5, but I am not sure. Any help on this will be appreciated!

System Specs:
Ubuntu: 22.04 
OpenMPI: 4.0.7 
mpi4py: 3.1.3

Comment: lscpu can tell you how many cores (not threads) are available.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I checked with lscpu, it has 10 cores. After some more digging, I found that problem is something else. I created another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74917169/mpi4py-enters-deadlock-after-using-spawn, please have a look at it.

Comment: MPI doesn't care about your hardware. You can easily start up a 100 processes on a 4 core machine. Usually you need to indicate to `mpiexec` how many slots there are. `mpiexec -usize 10` or so.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Victor! I found that problem is something else and I have created another question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74917169/mpi4py-enters-deadlock-after-using-spawn. Please have a look at it.