# mpi4py enters deadlock after using spawn

Tags: python, openmpi, spawn, mpi4py

I have following arrangement of code:

**parent.py**:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

... some code ...

for i in range(10):

    ... some code ...

    child_comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable, args=["runscript_airfoil.py"], maxprocs=9)
    child_comm.Barrier()
    child_comm.Disconnect()

    ... some code ...
```

**child.py**:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

... some code ...

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
comm.Barrier()
```

Primary objective here is to run `child.py` with multiple processors in a again and again. I used `Barrier()` method here since I wanted the program to wait until the `child.py` is executed.

But, the program just stops after the first iteration. I think the program is going into deadlock. Also, all the used processors by `child.py` should be freed so that I can use them in next loop.

I am new to MPI and mpi4py, so I don't know what functions to use where. Any help to implement this will be very useful.

**EDIT 1**:

Based on the comments, I modified the contents of the **child.py** file to the following:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

... some code ...

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
parent_comm = comm.Get_parent()
comm.Barrier()
parent_comm.Disconnect()
```

The program still gets stuck after the first iteration.

**EDIT 2**:

Based on the comments, I further modified the contents of the **child.py** file to the following:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

... some code ...

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
parent_comm = comm.Get_parent()
parent_comm.Barrier()
parent_comm.Disconnect()
```

The program doesn't enter deadlock, but when it tries to spawn in 2nd iteration, it gives following error: There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 9 slots that were requested by the application. My laptop has 10 processors in total, 1 is running the parent.py and rest 9 are running the child.py in first iteration. When the parent.py tries to spawn the child.py second time with 9 processors, it is not using the previously used 9 processors and it is trying to find 9 new processors (which is not available). I think the previous spawn is not exiting completely. To test this theory, I ran the original **parent.py** and **child.py** (from second edit) with maxprocs as 3 and loop three times. This works perfectly fine.

What command to use for freeing the processors completely?

**EDIT 3**:

My assessment at the end of edit 2 is **not** correct. I found that when I keep the maxprocs as 4 or less, it works fine irrespective of the number of loops. When I keep maxprocs as 5 or more, only then it starts giving "not enough slots" error. I am not sure what the problem here is.

Comment: I am not sure about the `mpi4py` part. before leaving, the child should `parent_comm.Disconnect()`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work. I have added an edit to the question.

Comment: the child should `parent_comm.Barrier()` instead

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I modified the contents of child.py based on your suggestion. The deadlock problem seems to be resolved but there is another error. Have a look at the edit 2.

Comment: try 'child_comm.Free()` after the disconnect.

Comment: I tried child_comm.Free() in parent.py file after child_comm.Disconnect(). It gave following error: "mpi4py.MPI.Exception: MPI_ERR_COMM: invalid communicator".

Comment: There is one more thing which I found: The value of the universe_size variable is 6, but the lscpu shows that I have 10 cores. Shouldn't universe_size be 10?

Comment: how do you start `parent.py` and how did you get the value for `universe_size`?

Comment: I start parent.py by: "python parent.py". I used MPI.UNIVERSE_SIZE and MPI is imported from mpi4py. I also tried MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_attr(MPI.UNIVERSE_SIZE). It's shows two different behaviors. When I run the parent.py as "python parent.py", it shows 1. But, when I run it as "mpirun -n 1 python parent.py", it shows 10. When I use MPI.UNIVERSE_SIZE, irrespective of the way I run it, it always shows 6.

Comment: what if you `mpirun -np 1 python parent.py` instead?

Comment: Irrespective of the way I run it, It shows not enough slots error. Also, see edit 3, if you haven't yet.

Comment: which versions of `mpi4py` and `Open MPI` are you using?

Comment: mpi4py: 3.1.3 and OpenMPI: 4.0.7

Answer (score 0):

Following MWE works without getting into deadlock (Thanks @Giles for the discussion in the comment section!):

**parent.py**:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD

for i in range(10):

    print("Start {}".format(i))

    child_comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Spawn(sys.executable, "child.py", maxprocs=9)
    child_comm.Disconnect()

    print("End {}".format(i))
```

**child.py**:

```
import time
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
time.sleep(comm.rank)
print(comm.rank)

parent_comm = comm.Get_parent()
parent_comm.Disconnect()
```

This is also described in [mpi4py tutorials](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#dynamic-process-management) (should have seen this before).

I was facing another error after this point. When I run parent.py as `python parent.py`, I used to get following output:

```
Start 0
0
3
4
7
1
6
2
8
5
End 0
Start 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 9
slots that were requested by the application:

  /home/pavan/miniconda3/envs/codelab/bin/python

Either request fewer slots for your application, or make more slots
available for use.

A "slot" is the Open MPI term for an allocatable unit where we can
launch a process.  The number of slots available are defined by the
environment in which Open MPI processes are run:

  1. Hostfile, via "slots=N" clauses (N defaults to number of
     processor cores if not provided)
  2. The --host command line parameter, via a ":N" suffix on the
     hostname (N defaults to 1 if not provided)
  3. Resource manager (e.g., SLURM, PBS/Torque, LSF, etc.)
  4. If none of a hostfile, the --host command line parameter, or an
     RM is present, Open MPI defaults to the number of processor cores

In all the above cases, if you want Open MPI to default to the number
of hardware threads instead of the number of processor cores, use the
--use-hwthread-cpus option.

Alternatively, you can use the --oversubscribe option to ignore the
number of available slots when deciding the number of processes to
launch.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parent.py", line 30, in <module>
    child_comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Spawn(sys.executable, "child.py", maxprocs=9)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1931, in mpi4py.MPI.Intracomm.Spawn
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: MPI_ERR_SPAWN: could not spawn processes
```

My laptop has 10 cores (verified using lscpu and I have run scripts with 10 processors using mpirun command). I ran the script as `mpirun -n 1 python parent.py` but I still get the same error.

After a lot of messing around, I found that adding a small pause after Disconnect method in parent.py works:
**parent.py**:

```
import time
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD

for i in range(10):

    print("Start {}".format(i))

    child_comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Spawn(sys.executable, "child.py", maxprocs=9)
    child_comm.Disconnect()
    time.sleep(0.25)

    print("End {}".format(i))
```

**Output**:

```
Start 0
7
6
8
4
5
1
0
3
2
End 0
Start 1
7
8
1
6
5
3
2
4
0
End 1
```

I am not sure why this works, but I am proposing that before Disconnect method ends, for loop is trying to spawn next set of processes. So, adding a small pause gave some time for Disconnect method to finish. I am not sure if this is an usual thing when working with MPI (or mpi4py), but if there is an elegant way of overcoming this, please let me know.